# Is it possible to apply a read filter on a .pcap file using tshark based on the interface?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, packet-capture, tshark

Can I do something like :

`tshark -r filename.pcap -R -i wan0` ?

Where `filename.pcap` is the packet capture file being analysed and `wan0` is the interface for which I need to apply the filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal pcap format as used by tcpdump does not contain information about the interface name where a packet was captured. The pcapng format as used by tshark or wireshark by default does have this information. With pcapng one could apply a display filter like this:

```
tshark -r file.pcapng -Y 'frame.interface_name == "wan0"'
```

Of course, this makes only sense if the pcapng file contains packets captured on multiple interfaces. Otherwise this filter would just result in no packets or all packets. Specifically it will not help to capture on the `any` pseudo-interface since the pcapng will not contain the names of the various interfaces on the system but just show all packets captured on the single `any` pseudo-interface.

Comment: Oh.. So, the .pcap file is useless for identifying the interface and I need to recapture the packets in .pcapng format using tshark instead of the .pcap file, right?

Comment: @jackOfAll: if you want to filter by interface name you have to use pcapng, i.e. recapture with tshark or wireshark. But like I said, this kind of filter makes only sense anyway if the capture contains packets from multiple interfaces and these are also marked as such (instead of just `any`). It is not clear what you are trying to achieve in the first place with using such a filter.

Comment: Yeah I do have multiple interfaces that I need to collect packets from and compare them. As you said I tried any. But all the packet data had only 'any' in 'interface_name' property.